# Graphing periods between start and end date

Tags: spotfire

Wondering how you would approach this - as I'm currently a little stumped.

I have some base data which contains (amongst other fields) rows of account#, production start date, production end date and production cost.  I would like to be able to expand this as a monthly chart (assuming the cost is distributed evenly across the periods).  So, for example if the project runs for 6 months at a total cost of $60, I would like to graph 6 months of $10 cost each month.  There are many rows of data, each with their own start / end dates and costs.

Any thoughts?! Thanks.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? a RDMS or .xls file or...?

Comment: For now it's just an XLS

Comment: Well the best thing to do would be to unpivot it with 1 row for each month. It's pretty easy in SQL but i'm sure there is a vb solution as well

Comment: @Grant- Could you please attach a sample table with some dummy data?